# Set drawable in ImageSpan programmatically?

Tags: android, image, imagespan

Is there is any other way besides passing drawable to the constructor to set drawable in ImageSpan? I couldn't find any other way

Comment: Nope.  You'll need to replace that span with  new ImageSpan.  Or you could use a compound drawable like level list or state list that can change drawables.

Comment: @Gabe Sechan Basically, I want to make custom ImageSpan(Lazy image loader) which can download the drawable on the way if not available locally. But there is no way to set drawable to Imagespan

Comment: That you can do, just takes a little work.  Create a state drawable that has 2 states-  one a default to draw before its downloaded, and one the actual image.  Pass the ImageSpan that drawable.  Then download the drawable and change the state of the state drawable.  See http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/StateListDrawable.html